# Get data from file input in jQuery "get(0).files" is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a file input in asp.net view page and I would like to retrieve the data of the file in jQuery ajax call on button onClick event.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<td style="text-align:left">
    <input type="file" id="AttachmenteUploadFile" name="AttachmenteUploadFile" />
    <input type="button" id="btnUploadSubmit" value="Attach Document" />
</td>
</table>
```

I tried:

```
var fileInfo = $("#AttachmenteUploadFile").get(0).files; //error : undefined
//$("#AttachmenteUploadFile")[0].files[0]; //error : undefined or null reference
//$("#AttachmenteUploadFile").prop('files');
```

None of the above is not working. I am getting 'undefined'. Please check the attached image. But i can get the object of input file with $("#AttachmenteUploadFile")[0]

any idea why i am not able to fetch the file data? Thanks for any Help.

[Input File Browser Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZcro.jpg)

Comment: You would be more likely to receive a useful answer if you include a [mcve] that reproduces the issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue that, i  have IE version 11.0 but the Mode is set to 7. When i changed to Mode higher than 10 it was working and i am able to get the file information. Please find the attached image hot set the mode version.

[Change IE Mode Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U99Yi.jpg)